# YubiKey Bio for SSH login: Do I have to reauthenticate?

Tags: ssh, yubikey

I'd like to use YubiKey Bio for SSH-logins. I'm wondering how often I have to show my fingerprint for authentication when I start new sessions. What's the interval? If I start a new session every 5 minutes, do I need to use the key each time?

Comment: Interval for what? Do you mean you expect the SSH server to challenge you for re-authentication during a single session? Have you looked up the documentation? Do you know how FIDO 2 works with OpenSSH?

Comment: Let's say I open every 5min an ssh session. My question would be how often I have to show my fingerprint.

Comment: I think this is a question about `ssh-agent` or [connection sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2869/87770 "Master connection") with `ControlMaster` in ssh_config rather than a question about the security key itself.